# Autocomplete textbox not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

**I have 2 models: Education and College.In college i have name field which admin will enter and and i want this college name to b shown in education form when user types any letter i.e autocomplete textbox with college names**

following is the code in my education form.html.haml but i dont know why this code is not working...actually this code was already there when i got this project so not able to understand why autocomplete not working..

```
= f.label :college_id, "College<em>*</em><small>college name</small>".html_safe
= f.text_field :college_id, :value => (@education.college ? @education.college.full_name : "")
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {   
      $('#education_college_id').focus().autocomplete(#{colleges_names_arr});
});
```

But this is not giving any output.I am not able to understand what this code is doing?I am using jquery,autocomplete.js for this..  What should i write to get autocopmleted list of college names.Do i have to define colleges_names_arr method in the education model which will have all the college names from college model?

Comment: I would recommend using jQueryui. Very easy to use and you get the total handle of things. Watch this video, http://vimeo.com/21045304

Answer (score 0):

Try [chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) library which converts dropdown to autocomplete here you are showing college name to be autocomplete you can use collection select and use chosen. It will solve your purpose.